# Error occurs when using take(1000) but works fine when use take(10). How to change query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Following is the code that I’m trying to execute. I tested this in Entity Framework of C# directly and it worked fine. There are 1000 items in the string list. Also note if I reduce the number of items in the string list (change Take(1000) to Take(10)) everything works fine.

Also we can get this to work if we perform the query in 2 steps.

1.) Load the activity table to a memory structure (list of activity type)
2.) Apply the contains clause to the memory structure

However, performance of this method is pretty bad compared to direct querying of the table.

Please help with this.  How can I get a solution for this without compromising the performance?

```
In C# (dataEntities is the database context)

var actKeyList = dataEntities.uvw_Custom.RecordManagement.Activity
               .Select(a =>  a.locationId).Distinct().Take(1000).ToList();

var test = dataEntities.uvw_Custom.RecordManagement.Activity.Where(a =>
                        actKeyList.Contains(a.locationId))
               .ToList();

In my context

var actKeyList = Entity.Query<Custom.RecordManagement.Activity>()
                    .Select(a =>  a.locationId).Distinct().Take(1000).ToList();

var test = Entity.Query< Custom.RecordManagement.Activity>().Where(a =>
                       actKeyList.Contains(a.locationId))
                   .ToList();

This is the error I get. Stack trace
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Core.Data.Implementation.Sql.SqlEnumerableParameter.SetValue(SqlParameter parameter, Object value)
at Core.Data.Implementation.Sql.SqlDataContext.CreateParameter(String name, Object value)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Core.Data.Querying.Implementation.Provider.ExecuteObjectReader[T](Translator translator)
at Core.Data.Querying.Implementation.Provider.Execute[T](Expression expression)
at Core.Data.Querying.Query`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Dynamic.Workflows_5dfd76e48784428ea68c5f8cebf05843.ExecutionWorkflow.Activity53()
The type initializer for 'Core.Data.Implementation.Sql.SqlEnumerable`1' threw an exception.
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I just added the eooro to my question

Comment: It says that type initializer threw an exception. You have information about what kind of exception? What is the message in the exception? Which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: I cannot specifically identify from which line it throws the exception. I suppose it's when adding to the filtering list

Comment: From the exception stack trace it's noticeable that you are using EF Core. You need to specify that in the tags / question, and also the EF Core version you are using, because currently many issues like this are simply EF Core bugs.